# Get all facebook mutual friends - Android application

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to get all the facebook mutual friends from 2 users of my app, I need all of the mutual friends not just the ones who are also using my app.

This is the method I'm using:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "context.fields(mutual_friends)");
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}",
    params,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

in {user-id} im sending the id of the user im trying to get the mutual friends with.
When running the app I actually get the mutual friends, but when I generate the apk and try install it on another phone it doesn't work. Seems like I can only make it work with the user that created the app.

Comment: not possible. you can only get users who authorized your app too.

Comment: but i actually get the result i want when i use the app myself (with my own facebook account), but if a install the apk in another phone and log in with another facebook account i get null

Comment: All users involved must have granted `user_friends` permission to your app – the current app user, the user you want to get the mutual friends for – _and those friends_. Plus, if you want to call this endpoint for two users that are not friends, you need to provide the appsecret_proof as well – which means you must make this call from a server.)